# Is there a way to insert words into a gui application without getting any error?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I insert words into a gui listbox using pycharm? It normally gives me an AttributeError.

Comment: The way this site works, you include the code your using. Such as the code you use to insert words into your listbox, and then you include the complete error. Then maybe somebody can help you fix your code.

Comment: Welcome to the SO. You should look at the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)